# Drop down selection is not working in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, automation, protractor

Help me in fixing this issue. I have to select the value from the drop down below is my Locators. I have tried Css, XPath and Repeater to select the value. CSS and Xpath is displaying "No Element found." When using Repeater it is not displaying any error nor selecting the value in drop down. What else should i need to explain. timed out issue is occuring

```
<select class="form-control">
<option value="Select peripheral">Select peripheral</option>
<!-- ngRepeat: p in peripheral --><option data-ng-repeat="p in peripheral" value="" class="ng-binding ng-scope">CUCM_PG_1</option>
<!-- end ngRepeat: p in peripheral -->
</select>
```

Comment: What else do i need to explain. it is showing the timed out issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably try to wait for the options to load in the select drop down. Below code should work for the only `option` element that you've given in your code -

```
var elem = $('.form-control');
var optionsToSelect = elem.element(by.repeater('p in peripheral'));
elem.click().then(function(){
    browser.waitForAngular().then(function(){
        browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(optionsToSelect),10000)
        .then(function(){
            optionsToSelect.click();
        });
    });
});
```

If the above code still doesn't click the drop down element, then try sending in an enter command after the click on options element. Here's how -

```
browser.actions().sendKeys( protractor.Key.ENTER ).perform();
```

Similarly, you can select any option you want using the element locator. All you need to do is to replace the `var optionsToSelect = elem.element(by.repeater('p in peripheral'));` with your option locator.

If you have multiple options in the drop down and if you want to select all of them in series you can do so by iterating through the elements. Here's how -

```
var elem = $('.form-control');
var optionsToSelect = elem.element.all(by.repeater('p in peripheral')); //get all options with the repeater
optionsToSelect.each(function(eachOption){
    eachOption.click().then(function(){
        //Perform any operation that you want after clicking each option
        browser.sleep(1000);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: no it is not working
Error: Wait timed out after 10427ms displayed for both the try

Comment: Iam extremely sorry @Girish Sortur was actually using some other url where it does not have the option in the drop down. Now ur code is working. What as to be done when there is multiple options? pls help me so that in future ill use it

Comment: Thanks a lottttttttt @Girish Sortur